# How to move anchor elements in unwanted places

Tags: html, css

My website is providing anchor elements over about 100 pixels and 10 pixels from where I want them and there are too many. Can anyone fix this? I only want two.

I've reviewed my code and there are no more than wanted anchor tags. I don't know what I should do.

```
<footer class="w3-container">
<p>Made with <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp">W3.CSS</a> || <a style="border-radius: 8px; height: 36px;" id="logout" class="w3-button w3-text-white w3-red" href="logout.php">Logout</button></p>
</footer>
```

I expect two anchor but there are at least three. I don't know if this is just my computer or a program flaw.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any alignment issues with the code sample you have provided. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem (in the question itself), along with **clearly** stating what your desired result is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please do not expect us to go to your website and join it to figure out where your code error is. Add enough of the related code to your question so that we can see the issue. Then we'd be glad to help. Otherwise, this looks more like spam than a question. (thx)

Comment: Check the second `<a>` tag, you've got a closing `</button>` instead of `</a>` that could result in some weirdness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using to create the page? Also, your link element should close with the same tag. Like this:

```
<a style="border-radius: 8px; height: 36px;" id="logout" class="w3-button w3-text-white w3-red" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed your code. It looks like you are closing your second anchor tag with a `</button>`. Replace the `</button>` with `</a>`, a closing anchor tag.

The code you have provided only has two anchor tags, but your complaint is that there are "at least three." It seems like we are missing some of your code.

Also, in terms of positioning and sizing, you can reference these resources to start:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp